# how to add html attributes to text box field in rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, view

How can i generate the following html tag in rails?

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="request[job]" list="suggestions" >
```

i tried the following rails helper method, But it's not generating the above desired html tag.

```
<%= text_field_tag :job, :data => { :list=> "suggestions" } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly (Updated)

```
<%= text_field_tag "request[job]", '' ,:data => { :list=> "suggestions" }, class: "form-control"  %>
```

Comment: Check now, and fix your bug there!